# Nginx domain resolving issue

Tags: nginx, dns, proxypass, upstream-branch

I had a proxy server which redirects communications to some api on customer side via https. When I use configuration with set upstream variable (proxy_pass $upstream_endpoint$request_uri;), the DNS resolving for this domain (dynamic changing IP adress) is working well but I get response 403 unauthorized.

When I use configuration without upstream (`proxy_pass https://api-test.example.com/api/`), point directly to customer domain it works well, I am getting response 200 but DNS resolver is not working anymore..

Nginx config:

```
location /api-test.example.com/api/ {
            resolver 10.100.10.1 valid=5s;
            set $upstream_endpoint https://api-test.example.com;
            proxy_pass $upstream_endpoint$request_uri;
            #proxy_pass https://api-test.example.com/api/;
            proxy_ssl_name api-test.example.com;
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;
            proxy_set_header Host api-test.example.com;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Comment: `$request_uri` is not the same as `/api/` - are you missing a rewrite?

Comment: Hi Richard
Yes $request_uri is the same as /api/
Do you mean it should be as 

set $upstream_endpoint https://api-test.domain.com/api/;
proxy_pass $upstream_endpoint;

Comment: No, I mean that the value of `$request_uri` is equal to `/api-test.domain.com/api/` and not `/api/`.

Comment: its possible issue. How should i fixed it? just remove from proxy_pass $upstream_endpoint$request_uri;

Final should be:
proxy_pass $upstream_endpoint;  ??

Answer (score 0):

By adding a URI to the `proxy_pass` statement, the requested URI is rewritten before passing it upstream. See [this docuement](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

So the URI `/api-test.example.com/api/foo` is rewritten to `/api/foo`.

You can achieve the same behaviour with a `rewrite...break` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

```
location /api-test.example.com/api/ {
    rewrite ^/api-test.example.com(.*)$ $1 break;
    set $upstream_endpoint https://api-test.example.com;
    proxy_pass $upstream_endpoint;
    ...
}
```